# Form input comparison to sqlite3 database in node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, sqlite

I'm relatively new to using node.js and sqlite3. I'm trying to check to see if a users name and password entered thorough a form matches ones saved in an sqlite3 db. I want to raise an error if the username/password entered doesn't match those in the db, otherwise send the user to another page.

Relevant form:

```
<form action="/account" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="user">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="user" name="name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label  for="pass">Password:</label>
                <input type="password"  id="pass" name="password">
            </div>
           
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Database create and comparison to form:

```
var db = new sqlite3.Database(':memory:');
db.serialize(function() {
        
    db.run("CREATE TABLE Accounts (id INTEGER, username TEXT, password TEXT, fullname TEXT");

    db.run(`INSERT INTO Accounts VALUES (1, "bob", "password", "Bob Bobson")`);       
    });
});
db.close();

app.get('/account', function (req, res) {
    db.all('SELECT * FROM Accounts', function(err, rows){
        rows.forEach(function (row){
           if (row.username == req.body.user)
           //go to success page

           if (row.username != req.body.usr)
         //list error
    
        });
       
        res.send();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not wise to run a query and retrieve all the rows from accounts table. If the table is too big it will take a lot of time.
It's better to do a "get" query with parameters and retrieve the specific row if it exists. If it exists the row parameter in the function callback will NOT be undefined.

```
db.get("SELECT * from ACCOUNTS where username=? and password=?", 
 [req.body.user,req.body.password],function(err,row){
      if(typeof row!=='undefined' && row!=null){ console.log('user exists'); }
});
```